# Processing Grouped Field in php

Tags: php, html

I have a form with four fields describing a person: name,email,phone,institution affiliation.
I would like users to click on 'add more', to add more than one person. when adding two persons the html will be like

```
<input type='text' name='institution[]'>
<input type='text' name='name[]' >
<input type='text' name='email[]' >
<input tpype='text' name='phone[]' >

<input type='text' name='institution[]'>
<input type='text' name='name[]'>
<input type='text' name='email[]' >
<input tpype='text' name='phone[]' >
```

The array after posting to php looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => kemri
        [1] => eohs
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => james muriira
        [1] => agnes mburu
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => james@gmail.com
        [1] => agnes@gmail.com
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 12345
        [1] => 56565
    )

)
```

i need a logic for grouping them together in a more meaningful array: eg

```
Array(
 [0]=>Array(
     [0]=>kemri
     [1]=>james muriira
     [2]=>james@gmail.com
     [3]=>12345
     )
 [1]=>Array(
     [0]=>eohs
     [1]=>agnes mburu
     [2]=>agnes@gmail.com
     [3]=>56565
    )
)


)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code:

```
<?php
// PHP Code Here
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    echo '<pre>',print_r($_POST),'</pre>';    

$whiteListKey = array('institution','name', 'email', 'phone');
$countArray = array();
$dataArray = array();

foreach ($whiteListKey as $key => $value) {
    $countArray[] = count($_POST["$value"]);
}

// get max value from count array
$maxVal = max($countArray);    

for ($i=0; $i < $maxVal; $i++) { 
    foreach ($whiteListKey as $key => $value) {
        $dataArray[$i][] = $_POST[$value][$i];
    }

}

echo '<pre>',print_r($dataArray),'</pre>';

}    

// End Here Code
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method='POST'>
        institution<input type='text' name='institution[]'><br>
        name<input type='text' name='name[]' ><br>
        email<input type='text' name='email[]' ><br>
        phone<input tpype='text' name='phone[]' ><br>

        <hr>

        institution<input type='text' name='institution[]'><br>
        name<input type='text' name='name[]' ><br>
        email<input type='text' name='email[]' ><br>
        phone<input tpype='text' name='phone[]' ><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could just do something like this:

```
<input type='text' name='user[0][institution]'>
<input type='text' name='user[0][name]'>
<input type='text' name='user[0][email]'>
<input type='text' name='user[0][phone]'>

<input type='text' name='user[1][institution]'>
<input type='text' name='user[1][name]'>
<input type='text' name='user[1][email]'>
<input type='text' name='user[1][phone]'>
```

Where `0, 1, 3, 4` would be incremented with javascript after you click `Add more`

Comment: thank you for your response. Since i am generating these fields dynamically, it would be difficult for me to do since i have several field types. am sorry i cant paste the code because it's too long.

So would you/someone kindly show us how to process that kind of an array as asked in the question?
Thanks